# XCODE fails to create adhoc IPA

Tags: iphone

I have created both developer and distribution (adhoc) provisions. However, I can only create IPA in xcode with the share -> save to disk button using the developer provision.

If I use distribution provision, it just fails silently.

I have tried deleting the provision on the portal and recreated a new provision, still the same.

Any idea how to fix? Should I reinstall xcode? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us a few screenshots on **when** you clicked **which** button in Xcode? And, what's your Xcode version number, 3.2.5?

Answer (score 0):

- There are `developer certificates` that allow to install onto hardware physically connected to the machine where Xcode runs on.
- There are `Adhoc certificates`, created after on the developer web portal you entered the UDID of your user devices. That type is used used for adhoc distribution and the resulting IPA can be send to users to install via iTunes without going through the app store.
- There are `distribution (Release) certificates` that are required to put stuff into the app store.

In project properties ensure you have the correct certificate for the chosen build type selected.

When in doubt about the adhoc profile then delete it and copy the release profile across. Change the certificate from release to adhoc and try again.

You can test your own adhoc builds by doing a build and archive, then drag and drop the resulting IPA onto iTunes (apps tab) and do a sync.